# How does the MFC PropertyGrid control work in the dialog editor in visual studio?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, dialog, desktop

In the visual studio dialog editor i can add a MFC Property Grid control to the dailog. How can i customize its content, and set options like allowing the user to edit the contents of it when the program using it is running, or how i can change the contents of it using c++?
When i add something like a button or and edit control it displays on the dailog box when the program is running, while when i add a MFC Property Grid the dailog isnt even being displayed.
[image]

Here is a picture of the visual studio dialog editor and a MFC property control grid in the middle of the dailog with contents i dont know how to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple tutorial of CMFCPropertyGridCtrl：

1.Create a dialog-based MFC project, drag a CMFCPropertyGridCtrl into it, and adjust the size. Then change the ID for the control to IDC_MFCPROPERTYGRID_TEST, and use Add Varible to add a variable m_propertyGrid to the control. Change the setting of Notify to `True`.
[image]

`Description Rows Count refers` to the number of rows in the description section below.

`Enable Description Area` indicates whether to enable the following description function.

`Enable Header` indicates whether to start the header.

`Mark Modified Properties` indicates whether to highlight the changes.

2.Set interface
Add the following code in `OnInitDialog()`

```
HDITEM item; 
item.cxy=120; 
item.mask=HDI_WIDTH; 
m_propertyGrid.GetHeaderCtrl().SetItem(0, new HDITEM(item));
```

3. Add content

Add the following code in `OnInitDialog()`

```
CMFCPropertyGridProperty* pProp2 = new CMFCPropertyGridProperty(
        _T("choose"),
        _T("select"),
        _T(""));
pProp2->AddOption(_T("1"));
pProp2->AddOption(_T("2"));
pProp2->AddOption(_T("3"));
pProp2->AllowEdit(FALSE);  //Editing of options is not allowed

m_propertyGrid.AddProperty(pProp2);
```

The three parameters passed in when calling the constructor are `item name`, `default options` and `description text`.

Also, you could add drop-down menu:

```
CMFCPropertyGridProperty* pProp2 = new CMFCPropertyGridProperty(
        _T("choose"),
        _T("select"),
        _T(""));
    pProp2->AddOption(_T("1"));
    pProp2->AddOption(_T("2"));
    pProp2->AddOption(_T("3"));
    pProp2->AllowEdit(FALSE);  //Editing of options is not allowed

    m_propertyGrid.AddProperty(pProp2);
```

In addition, there are three similar projects:

```
CMFCPropertyGridColorProperty * pProp3 = new CMFCPropertyGridColorProperty(
    _T("colour"), RGB(0, 111, 200));
m_propertyGrid.AddProperty(pProp3);

CMFCPropertyGridFileProperty * pProp4 = new CMFCPropertyGridFileProperty(
    _T("open file"), TRUE, _T("D:\\test.txt"));
m_propertyGrid.AddProperty(pProp4);

LOGFONT font = { NULL };
CMFCPropertyGridFontProperty * pProp5 = new CMFCPropertyGridFontProperty(
    _T("select font"), font);
m_propertyGrid.AddProperty(pProp5);
```

Finally, This is the final program running interface:
[image]

Comment: it wont let me initalize a HCnd, and when i try to include the header needed it says it can't find it.

Comment: Could you provide the relevant code and the property settings of MFC Property Grid control? Because it is helpful to reproduce the problem.